# Atificial Supernovae

Tags: stars, supernova

I just [just learned](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/139550/57517) that stars have metals in their cores that could theoretically be harvested by injecting enough mass to cause a supernova.

Say someone wanted to do this to our Sun.

How would you calculate (roughly) the amount of mass you would need to inject into the Sun to make it explode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much iron would I have to shoot into the sun to blow it up?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79355/)

Comment: @KyleKanos I don't see any way to calculate the mass required to produce a supernova in that link.

Comment: You need to have a total mass of at least 8 solar masses for a type II supernova

Comment: @SamWashburn: Then I suggest reading the answers because both answers say it *can't be done*. Not only due to the mass constraints that Count Iblis comments, but also due to the temperature constraints (our sun's core is about 1000 times too cold to allow for silicon fusion which would produce iron).

Comment: @CountIblis It seems it wouldn't be efficient or easy, but, theoretically speaking what if I dropped a couple hundred Jupiter sized chunks of iron into the sun.  That should put it over the 8 solar masses.  Would it just ignite?  Or are there other things required?

Comment: In order for the star to explode due to the iron in the core, the star needs to be **supported** by the pressure from the fusion of silicon into iron. Simply shoving iron into the core would be a useless endeavor.

Comment: @Sam Washburn, no it wouldn't because Jupiter is only $1/1000$ mass of the Sun so even "a couple hundred Jupiter sized chunks” would not even double, much less octuple the mass of the Sun.

Comment: @Sean it's possible that Sam was saying size as in volume rather than mass - that puts it into the correct order of magnitude.

Comment: @Sean user121330 is right.  Jupiter sized as in volume, not in density.

Comment: @KyleKanos I wondered if there was other factors required.  Thanks.

Comment: @ Sam Washburn- "Say someone wanted to do this to our Sun."You aren't planning something like this are you? :O

Comment: @HarryDavid Um.. no? [hold the launch guys.. I think they're on to us..]  No, not at all, why would you say that?

Comment: @Sam Washburn- Oh, no reason- I'd better recall the Special-Forces guy's I ordered to raid your home! :)